# Should the 'group' tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are four [questions tagged [group]](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group), used in three different contexts:

- group delay:

  - [Difficulty understanding group delay concept](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/427824/difficulty-understanding-group-delay-concept)
  - [For what type of signals group delay of a filter should be taken into account?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/441533/for-what-type-of-signals-group-delay-of-a-filter-should-be-taken-into-account)
- group vector transformers:

  - [Dissimilar Vector Group Transformers fed from 2 dissimilar phased sources of power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/506338/dissimilar-vector-group-transformers-fed-from-2-dissimilar-phased-sources-of-pow)
- VHDL 'group' keyword:

  - [What is the purpose of groups in VHDL?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/652205/what-is-the-purpose-of-groups-in-vhdl)

I don't think the [group] tag adds value to any of these questions. Should this tag be removed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this tag adds no value so it should be removed. The other tags on the existing questions are sufficient.

Comment: I removed the [group] tags from those questions. I'm not sure what the requirements are to purge a tag altogether.

Comment: @Velvel there is a comment from a mod that this isn't really possible in a similar question about the `core` tag here in in meta from a few weeks ago.

Comment: @Velvel It will eventually be deleted by the system as long as it is removed from all questions.